# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Editor.enableReadOnlyMode is not a function (ckeditor)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to enable read only mode for my ckeditor but when I use `enableReadOnlyMode` doesn't work.

```js
import '../../../../public/assets/vendor/ckeditor5-41.2.0/build/ckeditor';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';


const Editor = ClassicEditor;
const ckeditor = CKEditor.component;
const editorConfig = {};
Editor.enableReadOnlyMode( 'my-feature-id' );


<ckeditor
class="ckeditor no-preflight"
id="ckeditor"
:editor="Editor"
v-model="form.description"
:config="editorConfig"
></ckeditor>
```

it shows me this error in console:

```
Form.vue:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Editor.enableReadOnlyMode is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be called once the ckeditor is ready, which probably won't be exactly when the Vue component is created or mounted, but the editor itself will emit `ready` event which you can use to then call editor functions.

```html
<ckeditor
  id="ckeditor"
  v-model="form.description"
  class="ckeditor no-preflight"
  :editor="Editor"
  :config="editorConfig"
  @ready="onReady"
></ckeditor>
```

```js
function onReady(editor) {
  editor.enableReadOnlyMode('my-feature-id')
}
```